# Unsupported engine for amqplib@0.4.2 node-red-contrib-amqp#installation

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

Have the latest node-red installed on Ubuntu 20.04?

Trying to add the node-red-contrib-amqp plugin as described on the GitHub page.

https://github.com/abreits/node-red-contrib-amqp#installation

```
$ sudo npm install -g node-red-contrib-amqp
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for amqplib@0.4.2: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <6 || ^6"} (current: {"node":"12.19.1","npm":"6.14.8"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: amqplib@0.4.2


$ node --version
v12.19.1
$ npm --version
6.14.8
```

Comment: Does someone have this perhaps working on a recent node-red version?  It could just be a recent upgrade that is a breaking upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMPQ seems no longer supported, at least I was unable to solve the errors in question after some hour or two. You also cannot downgrade to node `"node":">=0.8 <6` anymore.

The issue of your question, [amqplib not supported](https://github.com/abreits/node-red-contrib-amqp/issues/33), is open since March 2020.

This [answer to "AMQP working on node-red" from June 2021 in the discourse.nodered forum](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/amqp-working-on-node-red/46893/2) shows:

> - node-red-contrib-amqp2 hasn't been updated in over 4 years and is probably abandoned
> - node-red-contrib-amqp hasn't been updated in over a year and a half, there are 20 open issues and the author has had no GitHub since December of 2019.

You might still give it a last try and follow 
[node-red-contrib-amqp-ack 1.1.2](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-amqp-ack) with

```
sudo npm install -g node-red-contrib-amqp-ack
```

instead to get

[image]

Though in my case, that command threw the same error as your

```
sudo npm install -g node-red-contrib-amq
```

Therefore, consider using [MQTT with RabbitMQ and Node-RED](https://tewarid.github.io/2019/02/15/mqtt-with-rabbitmq-and-node-red.html) instead. `MQTT in` and `MQTT out` nodes are built-in in node-red:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

amqplib not support with your node version . So you will able to install new amqplib version or downgrade your node version (.8  6)

Comment: I'll try to reinstall