# npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { npm WARN EBADENGINE package: 'amqplib@0.4.2',

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform, amqp, node-red

I am trying to install node-red-contrib-amqp-ack package in a Google Cloud Server. The thing is I am using the node version v16.15.0 and npm version 8.5.5 and it gives me the following error I think due to this versions being too new.

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'amqplib@0.4.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=0.8 <6 || ^6' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.15.0', npm: '8.5.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

I tried installing an older version of node (v6.0.0 and also tried with the v5.9.0) and npm but then node-red doesn't work.
Does anybody know a solution to this?

ps.I am using Debian 11 on the server.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70747040/5529712

Comment: It looks like this package has not been updated in quite a while.  You might want to consider using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@meowwolf/node-red-contrib-amqp instead.

Comment: @GariSingh I tried to do that but it gives me the same error, thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by downgrading my node.red version to 1.1.1
using

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red@1.1.1
```

Comment: This is a really bad solution, you have just really degraded both capability and security of Node-RED and NodeJS to get one node to work. Fixing why the broken node thinks it needs that old version of NodeJS is the right way forward. (Also NodeJS versions that old will have a bunch of expired SSL/TLS certificates baked in so don't expect HTTPS requests to work)

Comment: @hardillb the NodeJS version is still the same, the only thing that I changed is the node-red version because that package isn't developed anymore for newer versions.

Comment: if that is the case then just use npm to manually install the node (and force it to install) in the up to date Node-RED userDir.